# Getting published streams from Live Repeater Edge using Wowza Java API

Tags: wowza

I have Java code that gets all the publisher streams using the Wowza Server-side API

```
appIns.getStreams().getPublishStreamNames()
```

This works great if this module runs on an origin application that has a stream pushed to it, however, when the application is set up as a Live Repeater Edge, it looks like the published streams from the upstream origin cannot be accessed via this api.

How can I get the published streams from the upstream server in the Server-side API?